# View view in activity

Tags: java, android, android-view

I am trying to make my activity work but then there is an issue in method `nextSong()`. The last line of it, `playorPauseMusic()` has an error:-

```
playoyPauseMusic (View) in PlaySongActivity cannot be applied to ()
```

I am not very sure what the issue is but think it is about the `(View view)`. I am very new to Java so if you could detail the issue, it would help a lot. Thanks;)

```
public void playorPauseMusic(View view) 
{
    if (player == null) {
        preparePlayer();
    }
    if (!player.isPlaying()) {
        if (musicPosition > 0) {
            player.seekTo(musicPosition);
        }
        player.start();
        getSeekBarStatus();
        btnPlayPause.setText("PAUSE");
        setTitle("Now Playing: " + title + " = " + artist);
        gracefullyStopWhenMusicEnds();
    } else {
        pauseMusic();
    }
}

private void gracefullyStopWhenMusicEnds()
{
    player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            nextSong();
        }
    });
}

public void stopActivities() {
    btnPlayPause.setText("PLAY");
    musicPosition = 0;
    setTitle("");
    player.stop();
    player.release();
    player = null;
}


private void nextSong()
{
    Song nextSong = songCollection.getNextSong(songId);
    if (nextSong !=null)
    {
        songId = nextSong.getId();
        title = nextSong.getTitle();
        artist = nextSong.getartist();
        fileLink = nextSong.getFileLink();
        coverArt = nextSong.getCoverArt();
        url = BASE_URL + fileLink;
        displaySong(title, artist, coverArt);
        stopActivities();
        playorPauseMusic();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post full logcat output of error?

Comment: error: method playorPauseMusic in class PlaySongActivity cannot be applied to given types;
required: View

Comment: Your method requires an instance of `View` as parameter but where you call it you did not pass a view parameter.

Comment: Just remove it from signature of `playorPauseMusic` method if you dont use the view.

Comment: i do need the parameter view, i did not include the whole codes for the activity. Hence, given that i need the parameter View, how would i go about to solve the issue as stated above?

Comment: you dont use the view parameter in `playorPauseMusic` method block. Do whatever you want in the rest of the activity. A method is also called **Block**. In java, the variables in a block are able to used by that block when you define a method like `public void playorPauseMusic(View view) ` the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your method `playorPauseMusic(View view)` has a parameter `View view`. This means that whenever you are calling the method you must provide an instance of View as a parameter. in the last line of the `nextSong()` method you call `playorPauseMusic()` without a view parameter, causing your error

Although it doesn't appear that you actually make use of the parameter, so you could change the method `playorPauseMusic(View view)` to just `playorPauseMusic()`

Comment: Hi, i do need the parameter View. Given that, how would i solve this issue?

Comment: @HarishRaaj you will need to find a way to either be able to pass the `View` through your program into next song to then further pass into `playorPauseMusic()` or you could consider making the `View` a class variable, or field. there's no way to tell for certain what will fix it for you but the structure of your program is probably the goto thing to change

Comment: It seems you require the `view` parameter to be able to hook up the method from the `onClick` on a component inside the layout. Since you don't actually use the parameter, just call the method passing `null` - `playorPauseMusic(null);`